# JavaFX: pause until animation finishes

Tags: java, animation, javafx, pause

I have a basic javafx program where a rectangle, simulating an elevator, must move up and down at the push of 'up' and 'down' buttons. I have successfully implemented the code to do this below:

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == upButton) {
        //this should all be put into a 'slideNode' method
        TranslateTransition translateTransition1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(500), theElevator);
        translateTransition1.setByX(0);
        translateTransition1.setByY(-50);
        translateTransition1.setCycleCount(1);
        translateTransition1.setAutoReverse(false);
        translateTransition1.play();
    }
}
```

The issue I need to solve is what happens when the elevator is partway through this motion and the button is pressed again - the elevator doesn't get the full motion it would have if I waited until it reached its first destination to press the button again!

I understand why this happens, but I'd like to know if there's a way to solve this. I imagine there should be some piece of the API similar to the following, which I can toss at the end of my code:

```
Pause pause = new Pause(Duration.millis(500));
pause.pause();
```

Does such a thing exist? How would you solve my problem?

Comment: Can you add a variable to your translateTransition1. Something like isPlaying that gets flipped to true at the start of the animation and then false at the end. That way you can check if it's playing before starting the animation again.

Comment: The `TranslateTransition` already has a [`statusProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#statusProperty) you can observe. It's value will be `RUNNING` while the animation is running.

Comment: James, if that was an answer and not a comment I'd select it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the button while the `TranslateTransition` is playing:

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == upButton) {
        //this should all be put into a 'slideNode' method
        TranslateTransition translateTransition1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(500), theElevator);
        translateTransition1.setByX(0);
        translateTransition1.setByY(-50);
        translateTransition1.setCycleCount(1);
        translateTransition1.setAutoReverse(false);
        translateTransition.statusProperty().addListener((obs, oldStatus, newStatus) -> 
            button.setDisable(newStatus==Animation.Status.RUNNING));
        translateTransition1.play();
    }
}
```